GCC "error adding symbols: file in wrong format collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status" when making C
Undergraduate GCC newbie here. I am working on a simple C program in Ubuntu 22.04.2 ARM64. The  C program is prewritten and provided for me to debug using GDB, so the program itself should be "makable". When I typed "make" into terminal, the error was like this:
parallels@ubuntu-linux-22-04-02-desktop:~/ece220/ece220_mps/mp7/dist/primeNumber$ make
gcc -c -Wall -o primeNumber.o primeNumber.c
gcc -Wall -g primeNumber.o isPrime.o -o primeNumber -g
/usr/bin/ld: isPrime.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/bin/ld: isPrime.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/bin/ld: isPrime.o: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:15: primeNumber] Error 1


I tried and checked if there were any spelling mistakes and turned out there weren't. I also tried "make clean" and "make" again but the same error appeared again.
I know this might be a stupid question to ask but I feel really troubled. I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me.
Regards
